# Glass material in eevee is not working properly

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, glass

I am trying to follow a tutorial from Ducky3D.
https://youtu.be/09IQopONnoY
Here is the link for that tutorial. So my problem is, I can't see any kind of light source through the glass in eevee. Although the objects lit by those light sources are visible. In order to follow the tutorial the light source has to be visible. In this case that image is the light source . But it's not visible in eevee. Again it's visible in cycles. In the tuturial Ducky did the final render in cycles though while working he was using eevee, and that image was visible. Here are some screenshots . You might find these useful while answering,
[image]

As you can see the picture is there .(eevee)
[image]
although from the otherside that picture is not visible.(eevee)
[image]
in this case in cycles the image is visible (cycles).
I don't wanna use cycles to render this image as my pc is weak.(it took 30 minnutes to render a scene in cycles). And the scene looks much better in eevee.
So what is the problem ? What can I do to make the image visible in eevee ?

Comment: Hello, please share your glass object + your emission object, there must be something in your settings that doesn't make it work: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Okay..  Shreen space reflection - check, refraction -check, screen space refraction - check,...  So far every thing is allright. I just changed the shadow mode to none in order to let the light pass through.

Comment: In EEVEE, did you change your material's Blend Mode to something other than "opaque"?

Comment: I didn't try that yet... . But as far I know we change the blend mode to alpha hashed from opaque in case of transperant shader. Glass shader has nothing to do with it. But I will give it a try!  It could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this for your glass shader in EEVEE:

[image: EeveeTrans]